# How to make items clickable (onpick) in Seaborn scatterplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm using `sns.scatterplot` function to analyze some data. It would be very helpful for me if I could pick an object on the plot by clicking on it and execute a function. Matplotlib has [`onpick`](https://matplotlib.org/api/backend_bases_api.html#matplotlib.backend_bases.PickEvent) event which does the trick, but I couldn't find how could I do the same with Seaborn. It is using Matplotlib internally, so I think that it is possible somehow to attach `onpick` handler to it.

The reason I'm using Seaborn instead of basic Matplotlib plot is that I need `hue` parameter.

Here is basically the code that I'm using:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def _onpick(event):
    # ... process selected item
    print("Picked!")

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
ax = sns.scatterplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", data=tips)

# how to assign an 'onpick' callback

plt.show()
```

Comment: If everything else fails, you can always get a handle to the artists via filtering the output of `ax.get_children()` for the elements that you want to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as in any other case, you define the `picker` argument and connect the callback function.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def onpick(event):
    # ... process selected item
    print("Picked!")

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
ax = sns.scatterplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", hue="time", data=tips, picker=4)

ax.figure.canvas.mpl_connect("pick_event", onpick)

plt.show()
```