# How do I get a legend along my categorical colored scatter plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, scatter-plot

I have created a scatter plot with mathplotlib and colored it using a column in my dataframe. Now, I want to add a legend to make clear what color represents what data. However, simply adding `plt.legend()` without labels doesn't do the trick and adding labels in my `plt.scatter` command does neither.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib notebook

color = {
    "Africa" : "red",
    "Americas" : "green",
    "Eastern Mediterranean": "blue",
    "Europe" : "yellow",
    "South-East Asia": "black",
    "Western Pacific" : "orange"
}

data.columns = ['Country', 'GDP', 'Region', 'Air pollution (ug/m3)']
data['Color'] = data['Region'].map(color)

plt.scatter(data['GDP'], data['Air pollution (ug/m3)'], picker= 0, c = data['Color'], label = data['Region'])
plt.legend()
    
def onpick(event):
    origin = data.iloc[event.ind[0]]['Country']
    plt.gca().set_title('Selected item came from {}'.format(origin))

plt.gcf().canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)
```

Currently, it looks like this:

[image: 1]

However, I would the legend to look like the `color` dictionary, with the color as a bullet point and behind that the `Region`. How would I best do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your are not interested in using exactly those colors, you can simply use a `sns.scatterplot` like in this code, without the need to map each color:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from random import sample
import seaborn as sns

N = 100
data = pd.DataFrame({'GDP': np.random.random(N),
                     'Air pollution (ug/m3)': np.random.random(N),
                     'Region': sample(['Africa',
                                       'Americas',
                                       'Eastern Mediterranean',
                                       'Europe',
                                       'South-East Asia',
                                       'Western Pacific']*N, N)})

sns.scatterplot(data = data,
                x = 'GDP',
                y = 'Air pollution (ug/m3)',
                hue = 'Region')
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor = (1.05, 0.98), loc = 'upper left')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Otherwise, if you want to mantain your colors, you can re-define the cycler:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from random import sample
import seaborn as sns
from cycler import cycler

N = 100
data = pd.DataFrame({'GDP': np.random.random(N),
                     'Air pollution (ug/m3)': np.random.random(N),
                     'Region': sample(['Africa',
                                       'Americas',
                                       'Eastern Mediterranean',
                                       'Europe',
                                       'South-East Asia',
                                       'Western Pacific']*N, N)})

default_cycler = cycler(color=['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'black', 'orange'])
plt.rc('axes', prop_cycle=default_cycler)

sns.scatterplot(data = data,
                x = 'GDP',
                y = 'Air pollution (ug/m3)',
                hue = 'Region')
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor = (1.05, 0.98), loc = 'upper left')

plt.show()
```

[image]

---

Regarding interactivity, as exposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56043822/9214357):

> Just as in any other case, you define the `picker` argument and connect the callback function

In your case:

```
sns.scatterplot(data = data,
                x = 'GDP',
                y = 'Air pollution (ug/m3)',
                hue = 'Region',
                picker = 4)
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor = (1.05, 0.98), loc = 'upper left')

def onpick(event):
    origin = data.iloc[event.ind[0]]['Country']
    plt.gca().set_title('Selected item came from {}'.format(origin))

plt.gcf().canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great answer, those look great. I tried to use the seaborn before, but I couldn't work out the interactivity with it. How would I make the onpick event work with it?